# DeclareMathOperator in Matlab Latex

Tags: matlab, latex

I'm using the Matlab publishing tool Latex to add formula's

I want to show an error function: e.g. erf(x). The problem is that this function is not default in latex. As a result you will get something like "*er* **f**(x)".

Now, in Latex you can add this new function using.

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\erf}{erf}
```

However, Matlab does not accept this.

```
Error updating Text.

 Character vector must have valid interpreter syntax: 
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\erf}{erf}$$
```

I've been looking around, but found nothing, so help would be appreciated.

Comment: Matlab's LaTeX parsing is fairly limited. Could you do `\textrm{erf}` or similar instead?

Comment: @David thanks, your suggestion at least fixes it for now.

Comment: Try `\newcommand{\erf}{\ensuremath{\operatorname{erf}}}`.

Comment: @P.Siehr MATLAB seems to accept the command, but publishing fails: "$$\newcommand{\erf}{\ensuremath{\operatorname{erf}}} \erf(1)$$" just prints the full line `$$\newcommand{\erf}{\ensuremath{\operatorname{erf}}} \erf(1)$$`

Comment: I have never used Matlab to parse LaTeX, sorry. Is there a way you can provide a working minimalistic example to test this? // I only have one thought, probably due to ignorance:  In general commands, such as `\newcommand` or `\DeclareMathOperator` should be stated in the preamble, i.e. before `\begin{document}`.  Does Matlab support that, e.g. `\usepackage{}` ?

Comment: @P.Siehr no, it does not: MATLAB only supports LaTeX equations: see [here](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/marking-up-matlab-comments-for-publishing.html#btj5jsh-1). Thank you for your attempt to help, but I know how to do it in LaTeX. I need support on how to do it in MATLAB